# How to move cursor with arrays data?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move the cursor when you press the button with 2 arrays;
array with "X" coordinates and array with "Y" coordinates, this arrays have coordinates from my txt files. My question is; can I read all data on my arrays and move the cursor with that?

This is one application move the cursor with specific coordinates. That is why my text files have the coordinates. I don't know if I can move the cursor with data on arrays.

This is one example of what I'm trying

```cs
private void cursor_track_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> linesX = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordinate\CoordX.txt").ToList();
    List<string> linesY = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordinate\CoordY.txt").ToList();
    string[] arrayX = linesX.ToArray();
    string[] arrayY = linesY.ToArray();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        x = arrayX[i];
        y = arrayY[i];
        Cursor.Position = new Point(x , y);
    }
}
```

How can I move the cursor with the data on my arrays?

Comment: You need to parse the strings to numbers, and use the length of the array instead of the hardcoded number 20. What have you tried to do so?

Comment: only count the first 20 numbers on my array to see if work.

Comment: So read [ask], describe what you want to do, what you observe and what you have tried to resolve that.

Comment: Ok, i will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to call ToArray() to index your array, List has indexers, so perfectly you can call

```
linesX[1]
```

You can iterate your array with your for loop or with a foreach, both options, array and List implement IEnumerable. So

```
foreach(var element in linesX)
```

or

```
foreach(var element in arrayX)
```

both are fine.
If your txt has the coordinates as integers, you need to cast the data to int in order to use them later as part of the parameters of Point. My advice, if you want to move through all your coordinates, first read your files and save them as Point into a `List<Point>` so you can later move comfortably through that list using the foreach statement.

Something like this

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> linesX = new List<string>{"1","2","4"};
    List<string> linesY = new List<string>{"-1","-2","-4"};

    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    //assuming both linesX and linesY has the same lenght
    for (int i = 0; i < linesX.Count; i++)
    {
        Point p = new Point(int.Parse(linesX[i]), int.Parse(linesY[i]));
        points.Add(p);
    }

    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Point coordinate X,Y={point.X},{point.Y}");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you give me one more example? im new with the List